# How to configure Solr suggester?

Tags: java, solr, autocomplete, autosuggest, search-suggestion

In **solrconfig.xml**,

Added a search component as below,

```
<searchComponent class="solr.SuggestComponent" name="suggest">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">suggest</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FSTLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">suggestions</str> //indexed field of type textspell
    <str name="weightField">price</str><!-- 
    <float name="threshold">0.005</float> -->
    <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Then added a request handler to handle suggestions as below,

```
<requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
<lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggest</str>
</lst>
<arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
</arr></requestHandler>
```

In **schema.xml** added a `field` named `suggestions` as ,

```
<field  name="suggestions" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true" />
```

of `field type` `textSpell` defined as ,

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSpell" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer></fieldType>
```

After `restarting` and `reindexing` particular `core` named `libshelf` when I query,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/libshelf/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.build=true&suggest.dictionary=suggest&wt=json&suggest.q=c
```

the result is,

```
{
"responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 32
},
"command": "build",
"suggest": {
    "suggest": {
        "c": {
            "numFound": 0,
            "suggestions": []
        }
    }
}}
```

More over the since the `dicionaries` for suggestions are based on `indexed` fields `pagecontent` and `pagetitle`, have created two `copyfields` to `seed` the `suggesters` as below,

```
<copyField source="pagecontent" dest="suggestions"/>
<copyField source="pagetitle" dest="suggestions"/>
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: what kind of an issue?

Comment: No suggestions in response, But the pagecontent and pagetitle has almost 500+ text docs being indexed and stored in solr index... How to  let solr look into the field indexes ( pagecontent and pagetitle ) , read and suggest ? Am I missing any configuration here ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: len must be <= 32767; got 34826\ \ \ at org.apache.lucene.util.OfflineSorter$ByteSequencesWriter.write(OfflineSorter.java:479)

Comment: For solr5 and above , you can refer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862609/how-to-get-suggestions-in-solr-5-3-0